# SEO Friendly Urls 500 Server Error

Tags: php, friendly-url

I have the following in my htcaccess file:

```
Options +Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php # Remove .php from filename
RewriteRule ^profiles/([^/]+)\.php profiles.php?id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L] # Pretty url for Profile page
RewriteRule ^crime/([^/]+)\.php crime.php?id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L] # Pretty url for Crime page
RewriteRule ^edit_account/([^/]+)\.php edit_account.php?type=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L] # Pretty url for Edit Account Page
```

So far the .php part will be stripped from the file, but now when I try and use the profile page, by the following url: /profiles/1.php or /profiles/1, I get a 500 Internal Server Error. Is there anything wrong in the file?

Comment: Check if you have mod_rewrite installed. Also look for the error detail in the Apache error log

Comment: @Maks3w The mod_rewrite is installed, in the error log I get: [Sat Jul 13 13:03:09 2013] [error] [client *] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: /players_online.php

Comment: Now I have on all pages an 500 internal server error.

Comment: did you try to clear the cache

Answer (score 0):

If you host this website on remote server, ask from them are they blocked .htaccess. This is happened to me, Server administrators stoped .htaccess without given noticed.

Comment: It worked when I had this in the htaccess:

RewriteRule ^profiles/([^/]+)\.php profiles.php?id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^crime/([^/]+)\.php crime.php?id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^edit_account/([^/]+)\.php edit_account.php?type=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

And thought removing the .php extension of all files could be removed too, but after I did that it stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write `.php` once you wrote the rule to remove the extension

```
RewriteRule ^profiles/([^/]+) profiles.php?id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L] #without .php
```